# Outlook 2019 not syncing with IMAP account inboxes unless manually focussed on

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-outlook-2019

I recently moved someone from Outlook 2013 to Outlook 2019 on a Windows 10 machine. The user has 3 mailboxes that have already been added. The issue I'm encountering is that the inbox folders for these mailboxes don't synchronize with their online accounts unless the user opens up each one and waits a few minutes for the " Synchronizing 'Inbox'  " progress bar to run. This doesn't happen instantaneoulsy either as it should be, sometimes I have to focus on other mailboxes and then re-open the inbox I was originally focused on. The mail definitely populates as the " Synchronizing 'Inbox'  " progress bar runs but it only does so when an inbox folder is manually focussed on. This seems to only occur with the IMAP accounts, the "Send/Receive" progress bar runs as well but it doesn't seem to update any of the mailboxes unless the " Synchronizing 'Inbox'  " progress bar runs simultaneously with it. I've included and updated the automatic send/receive for each mailbox in Send/Receive Groups but with no luck. Has anyone else experienced this issue with any possible solutions I can try?

Comment: Make sure that your Outlook has been fully updated and repaired. A corrupted outlook profile can lead this issue, so please try creating and using a new Outlook profile via Control Panel > Mail > Show profile and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.

Comment: @JeffYang7 - Apologies for replying this late to your comment, I wasn't able to work on the machine as the user took it shortly after. It will come back though at some stage so I'll try and implement that new Profile if need be. It is on a 'new' profile currently after a previous restore job was done on it - ie. theres 2 profiles and Outlook is not the default anymore as it caused major issues that time. It only seems to be this specific IMAP account that has this trouble.

Comment: @JeffYang7 - I feel Outlook should just be able to sync with the boxes at regular intervals but it doesnt seem to be doing it as it does with say, the Gmail accounts that are also synced as IMAP accounts on it.